# Change src related to "Radio Button Checks"

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button, src

In my project I want change src part (ar-button's src) related to my radio buttons check.

For ex: When you check "Option 1" I want to change src part on ar-button. Than when you check Option3x(with checked option1 and option1x) I want to change src again.

I mean for all 64 combination of checks I want to change src.

Any help or suggestion would be great!

Thanks..

```html
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="diffuse" name="kumas" value="textues/kumas/2/pgwfpjp_2K_Albedo.jpg"checked>
                        Option1
                    </label>
            
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio"id="adiffuse" name="kumas" value="textues/kumas/1/oi2veqp_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                       Option 2
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="bdiffuse"name="kumas" value="textues/kumas/3/sjfvce3c_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                        Option 3
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="cdiffuse"name="kumas" value="textues/kumas/4/sjfvcjzc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                     Option 4
                    </label>
                    
                    
<br><br>




                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="diffuse1" name="kol" value="textues\kol\1\teqbcizc_2K_Albedo.jpg" checked>
                        Option 1x
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="adiffuse1" name="kol" value="textues\kol\2\tfjbderc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                       Option 2x
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="bdiffuse1"name="kol" value="textues\kol\3\tcnodi3c_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                        Option 3x
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="cdiffuse1"name="kol" value="textues\kol\4\tcicdebc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                      Option 4x
                    </label>
  

                </div>
            
            </div>

        </div>



<br><br>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="diffuse2" name="dugme" value="textues\metal\1\scksebop_2K_Albedo.jpg"  checked>
                       Option 1z
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="adiffuse2" name="dugme" value="textues\metal\2\se4objgc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                       Option 2z
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="bdiffuse2"name="dugme" value="textues\metal\3\se4pcbbc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                        Option 3z
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="cdiffuse2"name="dugme" value="textues\metal\4\shkxcgfc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
                     Option 4z
                    </label>


<br><br>
                    
                    
    <ar-button

    id="change" src="https://basebros.com/models/ar_base_tekli_koltuk_3d.glb"
    
    id="change2 ios-src="https://basebros.com/models/ar_base_tekli_koltuk_3d.usdz"
    
    title="3D-AR by BASE">
    
    <img class="arbuttonicon" src="Assets/evindebutton.png" width="170px" alt="AR-icon">
    
    </ar-button>
```

Comment: So you have 64 different sources that you want to change between based on the radio combination?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
const kumas = document.getElementsByName("kumas");
const kol = document.getElementsByName("kol");
const dugme = document.getElementsByName("dugme");
const arButton = document.querySelector("ar-button");
    
let sources = [[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]]]; /* Fill this with the sources. The first element is if the first option for kumas is selected, the second is for if the second option is selected, etc. The elements inside those elements are for each of the different options for kol, and the elements inside those elements are for each of the different options for dugme. */

function foo() {
    let kumasSelected;
    let kolSelected;
    let dugmeSelected;
    for(let i of kumas) {
        if(i.checked) {
            kumasSelected = kumas.indexOf(i);
        }
    }
    for(let i of kol) {
        if(i.checked) {
            kolSelected = kol.indexOf(i);
        }
    }
    for(let i of dugme) {
        if(i.checked) {
            dugmeSelected = dugme.indexOf(i);
        }
    }
    
    arButton.src = sources[kumasSelected][kolSelected][dugmeSelected];
}
```

Run the function each time you want to update the source.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just posted new codes. I tried on my site but it did not work what we are trying to do. Can you please check it what is wrong with it ?

Comment: And if you wanna try our project link is https://festive-montalcini-d79f26.netlify.app/deneme.html you have to open it on mobile device. It is Augmented Reality for android devices. When you click second option for kumas model on augmented reality have to change.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="diffuse" name="kumas" value="textues/kumas/2/pgwfpjp_2K_Albedo.jpg"checked>
        Option1
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio"id="adiffuse" name="kumas" value="textues/kumas/1/oi2veqp_2K_Albedo.jpg">
       Option 2
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="bdiffuse"name="kumas" value="textues/kumas/3/sjfvce3c_2K_Albedo.jpg">
        Option 3
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="cdiffuse"name="kumas" value="textues/kumas/4/sjfvcjzc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
     Option 4
    </label>
    
    
<br><br>




    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="diffuse1" name="kol" value="textues\kol\1\teqbcizc_2K_Albedo.jpg" checked>
        Option 1x
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="adiffuse1" name="kol" value="textues\kol\2\tfjbderc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
       Option 2x
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="bdiffuse1"name="kol" value="textues\kol\3\tcnodi3c_2K_Albedo.jpg">
        Option 3x
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="cdiffuse1"name="kol" value="textues\kol\4\tcicdebc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
      Option 4x
    </label>


</div>

</div>

</div>



<br><br>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="diffuse2" name="dugme" value="textues\metal\1\scksebop_2K_Albedo.jpg"  checked>
       Option 1z
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="adiffuse2" name="dugme" value="textues\metal\2\se4objgc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
       Option 2z
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="bdiffuse2"name="dugme" value="textues\metal\3\se4pcbbc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
        Option 3z
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="cdiffuse2"name="dugme" value="textues\metal\4\shkxcgfc_2K_Albedo.jpg">
     Option 4z
    </label>


<br><br>
    
    
<ar-button

src="https://basebros.com/models/ar_base_tekli_koltuk_3d.glb"


title="3D-AR by BASE">

<img class="arbuttonicon" src="Assets/evindebutton.png" width="170px" alt="AR-icon">

</ar-button>  



<script>

const kumas = document.getElementsByName("kumas");
const kol = document.getElementsByName("kol");
const dugme = document.getElementsByName("dugme");
const arButton = document.querySelector("ar-button");
    
let sources = [[["https://basebros.com/models/ar_base_ayakkabi.glb"],["https://basebros.com/models/ar_base_camasir_makinesi_3d.glb"],["https://basebros.com/models/ar_base_kahve_makinesi_3d.glb"],["https://basebros.com/models/ar_base_nintendo.glb"]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]]]; /* Fill this with the sources. The first element is if the first option for kumas is selected, the second is for if the second option is selected, etc. The elements inside those elements are for each of the different options for kol, and the elements inside those elements are for each of the different options for dugme. */

function foo() {
    let kumasSelected;
    let kolSelected;
    let dugmeSelected;
    for(let i of kumas) {
        if(i.checked) {
            kumasSelected = kumas.indexOf(i);
        }
    }
    for(let i of kol) {
        if(i.checked) {
            kolSelected = kol.indexOf(i);
        }
    }
    for(let i of dugme) {
        if(i.checked) {
            dugmeSelected = dugme.indexOf(i);
        }
    }
    
    arButton.src = sources[kumasSelected][kolSelected][dugmeSelected];
}
</script>
```